# Endless pulseaudio error logging: failed to acquire autospawn lock

Tags: pulseaudio

I have an issue with pulseaudio logging error messages in a loop and wonder how I can fix them:

```
Aug  7 20:22:17 s pulseaudio[25638]: lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
Aug  7 20:22:17 s pulseaudio[25638]: main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock /tmp/.esd/sock
Aug  7 20:22:18 s pulseaudio[25644]: module-protocol-stub.c: Failed to create socket directory '/tmp/.esd/socket': Permission denied
```

after deleting /tmp/.esd I get the following error:

```
Aug  7 20:22:32 s pulseaudio[25690]: lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
Aug  7 20:22:32 s pulseaudio[25690]: main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
Aug  7 20:22:37 s pulseaudio[25694]: core-util.c: Home directory /var/lib/gdm not ours.
```

Comment: What are the permissions of `/tmp` ? Use `ls -lad /tmp`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your /etc/security/limits.conf :

```
@audio          -       rtprio          65
@audio          -       nice           -10
@audio          -       memlock         40000

@pulse-rt       hard nice -20
@pulse-rt       soft nice -20
```

Also you have to add your user to the pulse-rt group.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the following in `/var/log/syslog` on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
Mar 24 09:41:19 ripple pulseaudio[4838]: [autospawn] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/112/pulse): No such file or directory
Mar 24 09:41:19 ripple pulseaudio[4838]: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
Mar 24 09:41:19 ripple pulseaudio[4838]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
Mar 24 09:41:21 ripple pulseaudio[4840]: [autospawn] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/112/pulse): No such file or directory
Mar 24 09:41:21 ripple pulseaudio[4840]: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
Mar 24 09:41:21 ripple pulseaudio[4840]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
Mar 24 09:41:23 ripple pulseaudio[4844]: [autospawn] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/112/pulse): No such file or directory
Mar 24 09:41:23 ripple pulseaudio[4844]: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
Mar 24 09:41:23 ripple pulseaudio[4844]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
```

On my system, consulting the file `/etc/passwd` shows that user `112` is `lightdm`, which is a display (login) manager.  I don't use `lightdm`. I manually stop `lightdm` after each reboot.  Nevertheless, some `lightdm` processes where hanging around.  From `htop`:

```
  PID  PPID USER      START   TIME+  PRI  NI  VIRT   RES  DATA   SHR S CPU% MEM% Command
 8273  2124 lightdm   Mar20  6:42.31  20   0  404M  5108  224M  3936 S  0.0  0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sou
 2124     1 lightdm   Mar20  0:44.20  20   0 39800  2128   620  1572 S  0.0  0.0 init --user --startup-event indicator-s
 8265  2124 lightdm   Mar20  0:00.00  20   0  257M  3016  216M  2484 S  0.0  0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-blu
```

I did a `sudo kill 2124`.  All three processes went away, and the log messages stopped.

In @grm's case, @grm appears to be using the `gdm` display manager, but the principles may be the same.  Possible solutions are:

1) Make sure no processes associated with `gdm` are running, or, alternatively...

2) Recreate the `/tmp/.esd` and make sure the processes associated with `gdm` have write access to `/tmp/.esd`.

Good luck!